# Generate random bytes for TripleDES key C#

Tags: c#, tripledes

I need to generate byte array for TripleDES encryption. I don't want to use `.generateKey()` because I need to know the bytes in the key to pass them to another application.

Thanks for the replies but I forgot to mention one thing: the bytes have to be odd parity. Otherwise I can't generate a TripleDES key from them. I'm not so familiar with the odd parity, so I guess have to create a byte check if it has odd parity or not; then if it does put it in the array, otherwise not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to ensure the odd parity, you have to compute it yourself. This should do:

```
var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
var key = new byte[24];
rng.GetBytes(key);

for(var i = 0; i < key.Length; ++i)
{
    int keyByte = key[i] & 0xFE;
    var parity = 0;
    for (var b = keyByte; b != 0; b >>= 1) parity ^= b & 1;
    key[i] = (byte)(keyByte | (parity == 0 ? 1 : 0));
}

return key;
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
RandomNumberGenerator rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
byte[] key = new byte[24]; // For a 192-bit key
rng.GetBytes(key);

tripleDes.Key = key;
```

Note that [`RandomNumberGenerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.aspx) is suitable for crypto work (in terms of reasonably secure, hard-to-predict random data), whereas `System.Random` isn't.

Comment: RandomNumberGenerator rng = new RandomNumberGenerator.Create();

Answer (score 2):

But ... what's the problem with just:

```
TripleDES provider = TripleDES.Create();

byte[] key = provider.Key;
```

There you get your key used by the en- and decryptor created with this instance.

Note that the other answers lack a [`TripleDES.IsWeakKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledes.isweakkey.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The [GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.getbytes.aspx) method returns crypthographically strong sequence of values:

```
        var rng = System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
        byte [] barr = new byte[128];
        rng.GetBytes(barr);
        foreach (var b in barr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(b);
        }
```

Comment: Thnx, thats working but look at my edited question. I forgot to say about the odd parity.

Answer (score -1):

What about     `Random.NextBytes()`

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextbytes.aspx).

Comment: `Random` isn't secure for cryptographic use.